# Replace multiple strings from a textfile

Tags: c#

I need to replace multiple strings in a textfile. This is my code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
string Text = File.ReadAllText(temp);
list.Add(Text.Replace("name", name));
list.Add(Text.Replace("name2", name2));
list.Add(Text.Replace("1.0000", CR));
list.Add(Text.Replace("0.6590", CG));
list.Add(Text.Replace("0.0000", CB));
foreach (string txt in list)
{
    File.WriteAllText(path, txt);
}
```

When I debug I can see the strings beeing replaced one after one, but when the next string is about to be replaced, the last string will then go back to its old value. Is there a way to replace multiple strings in a textfile?

Comment: You are adding the contents to a list with a single change for each item, and then overwriting the text file with them all in a loop (so only the last change will be saved)

Comment: And what do you mean by last string?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a list for this, but you do need to save the changes in the resulting string each time you do a replacement, otherwise you lose the changes.

The `Replace` method returns a new string with the replacement, so you can chain the calls to `Replace` and it will end up returning a string with all your changes.

Here's an example:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(temp)
    .Replace("name", name)
    .Replace("name2", name2)
    .Replace("1.0000", CR)
    .Replace("0.6590", CG)
    .Replace("0.0000", CB);

File.WriteAllText(path, txt);
```

Comment: This answer is better than mine. What is SO ettiquite - should I delete mine?

Comment: @ChrisH I think it's up to you. I usually either delete mine if it's mostly the same as another one that I think is better, or I highlight how mine is different and why someone might want to do it that way instead. Sometimes there isn't just a single *best* way to do something.

Comment: @ChrisH I would only delete your original answer in the cases where it's actually wrong, the other answer is enough "better" that yours is being downvoted, or yours came in enough earlier that it noticably out-scores the better answer. Otherwise, if one person came on the idea the, someone else might, too, and this lets that future person explicitly compare both options and see the community valued the other answer more. It could even be their situation is slightly different such that your answer is more helpful to them.